# Need some more information about WiFi Dongles

Tags: wireless-networking, router, dongle

I am considering buying a refurbished Dell desktop to use as my go to computer and only use my laptop "on the road".  I was told that the desktop in question comes with a wifi dongle.  I have never been exposed to such a device, and from the limited research I have just done, it seems that it works like a mobile hotspot connecting to broadband.  I have a great cable modem connected to Comcast Internet, and I have a fully functioning WIFI network in my home.  Will this dongle allow me to connect to that WIFI network.  I need a straight answer please, and as soon as you can provide one.  Thanks for your anticipated help.

Ron Albert

Comment: How about a link to the laptop you are looking at?

Answer (score 0):

The WiFi dongle works similarly to the WiFi card in a laptop - it will just more than likely be plugged into a USB port / PCI slot instead.

Assuming the dongle is from a reputable brand and drivers are available online or on an included disc, it should work fine.

Comment: Thanks for that answer JSK.